# Folding of PHPDoc comments on open not working in Eclipse Luna (why)?

Tags: eclipse, phpdoc, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-luna

why do these checkboxes seem to have no effect for me?

all PHPDoc comments are still expanded when I open a PHP file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not real answer but:

This look like classic bug in sofware. You should report it on official eclipse bugzilla (https://bugs.eclipse.org). Please add to your bug some additional informations, like:

- It's php project and/or external file?
- Luna version (4.4.0 or 4.4.1)
- Example (broken) file
- Logs (if any)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that it's a "PHP file" from the perspective of your editor.  I know some old file extensions are not recognized as such by default, so I had to add them to the configured list.  I've not seen issues with folding in Luna since I started using it for PHP stuff a month ago.